# Datediff in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I want to calculate the difference between two consecutive dates.
I want something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-` and `lead()`:

```
select date, (lead(date) over (order by date) - date) as difference
from t;
```